# What would the value of hyphen actually look like in this instance used to refer to stdin for this archive command?

Tags: ubuntu, find, tar, gzip, stdin

I am following a guide to learn terminal commands and have encountered the use of hyphens to refer to stdin in the following command used to find all files named 'file-A' within the directory playground. I understand it's usage to refer to the files found by the find command which are of course piped to tar and set to be read as a file using the --files-from= option. I do not understand it's usage in defining the intermediary name of the archive before being renamed by the gzip command.

```
 find ./playground -name 'file-A' | tar -cf - --files-from=- | gzip playground.tgz
```

Would the value of stdin not be a list of paths defined in the stdin file? if so how can this be an acceptable name for the archive?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find it in the `tar` manual. However `-` is often used by tools as a pseudo-filename referring to stdin or stdout. `tar` is using if for both. `-f -` saying output to `stdout` and `--files-from=-` saying get a list of file-names from `stdin`. The in and out are implied, these options expect an output and input respectively.

Also: `gzip` is not renaming. And there are no temporary files, data is passed via pipes.

Comment: Ah I see thank you so it does not create a filename with the value of Stdin but send a the archive to stdout. Very helpful, have a nice day